# Can we have two different session strategy for anonymous user and authenticated user with Spring Security

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

In my case, I'm getting a lot of anonymous user requests which end up stacking up redis with lots of anonymous sessions.
Is there any way for me to have different session strategy for anonymous user and authenticated user i.e. stateless and always respectively , OR possibly avoiding to store anonymous sessions / reducing the expiry time of anonymous sessions.

I'm currently using spring security 4.0.